# Using makefile check if symlink exists and create if it doesn't

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

In a makefile, I need to check if the symlink `include/libraries/libxyz.so` exists. If not, I want to create one by running

```
ln -s libxyz.so.1 libxyz.so
```

at include/libraries. How do I do this?

Comment: do you also want  to check if the target file is a link or not, and what would you do if a file/link already exists ?

Comment: the target is always a link, if it already exists just print something

Comment: Is there a reason not to use: include/libraries/libxyz.so: ln -fs libxyz.so.1 $@ The -f option to ln will force the removal of existing files (see ln --help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash you can add the following shell instructions in you makefile:

```sh
if [ -f include/libraries/libxyz.so ] ; then echo "something";else ln -s include/libraries/libxyz.so.1  include/libraries/libxyz.so;echo "linked";fi
```

Comment: the library libxyz.so.1 is inside the "include/libraries/" , so what would be change

Comment: @melwin_jose updated locations according to your comments and questions

Comment: `if [[ -f include/libraries/libuv.so ]]; then echo "symlink exists"; else echo "Creating symlink..."; ln -s include/libraries/libuv.so.1 include/libraries/libuv.so; fi `
Creating symlink...
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘include/libraries/libuv.so’: File exists
make: *** [default] Error 1 ... This what i get when i run it second time

Comment: `if [ -L 'include/libraries/libuv.so' ]; then echo "libuv.so symlink exists"; else echo "Creating symlink libuv.so..."; cd include/libraries/ ; ln -s libuv.so.1 libuv.so; fi ` this worked for me, with the long path to the link gcc was not able to pick the library

Comment: @melwin_jose -L is insufficient because a file **might** already exist with the same name

Answer (score 2):

This rule will work:

```
include/libraries/libxyz.so:
    ln -s libxyz.so.1 $@
```

Comment: care to provide a bit more explenation?